# Can anyone explain why setting a block attributes source to a data-attribute doesn't work?

Tags: block-editor, html

I created a block with a single attribute, formId. This was configured as follows:

```
attributes: {
    formId: {
        type: "string",
        source: "attribute",
        selector: "form.customForm",
        attribute: "data-formId",
    },
},
```

Both edit and save functions simply returned the following markup on initial save, with {formId} getting replaced by user input:

```
<form class="customForm" data-formId={formId}></form>
```

Here is the relevant portion of my Edit function (can confirm all my imports worked):

```
class customFormEdit extends Component {
constructor() {
    super(...arguments);

    this.onSubmitId = this.onSubmitId.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        isEditing: !this.props.attributes.formId,
    };
}

onSubmitId(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { formId } = this.props.attributes;
    if ({ formId }) {
        this.setState({ isEditing: false });
    }
}

render() {
    const { attributes, setAttributes } = this.props;

    const { formId } = attributes;
    const controls = (
        <BlockControls>{formId && <Toolbar></Toolbar>}</BlockControls>
    );

    if (this.state.isEditing || !formId) {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                {controls}
                <Placeholder label="Form">
                    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitId}>
                        <TextControl
                            placeholder={__("Enter form ID here…")}
                            value={formId}
                            onChange={(value) => setAttributes({ formId: value })}
                            className={"components-placeholder__input"}
                        />
                        <Button isLarge type="submit">
                            {__("Set ID")}
                        </Button>
                    </form>
                </Placeholder>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <CustomForm formId={formId} />
        </Fragment>
    );
}
export default customFormEdit;
```

Here's my custom form component:

```
    const CustomForm = (props) => {
    return (
        <form
            className={__("customForm")}
            data-formId={props.formId}
        ></form>
    );
};

export default CustomForm;
```

And here's my Save function:

```
export default function save({ attributes }) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save({
        className: "form-container",
    });

    return (
        <div {...blockProps}>
            <CustomForm formId={attributes.formId} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

However after refreshing the editor, I'd get form validation issues, as my attribute couldn't be read from the HTML data-attribute where I'd saved it. Eventually I just removed the attribute source altogether, so the attribute could simply be read from the block's comment delimiter, and my block works as expected.

But I still can't understand why the attribute couldn't be read from the element's data-formId attribute? Does anyone have a working example?

Comment: From your updated question, it sounds like the issue is unrelated to the error and is related to how your using the ID on the front end. Is that right? Can you include that code?

Comment: Have updated to include my Edit and Save functions, all I was trying to achieve was have the user enter a formId in Edit, and then return the HTML markup described above.

Comment: I suspect the issue is the way you've written `data-formId`. I have a feeling that at some point this is being interpreted as `data-form-id`, as `form-id` would be represented as `formId` in JavaScript. Can you try changing all references to use `data-form-id`?

Comment: Holy expletive Batman, it worked! 

Thanks for your help, unfortunately the formatting of data-formId is required by 3rd-party code, so will have to find a workaround, but at least I understand the issue now!